# GenericAPIView should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method

Tags: django

```
class GenericAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView,mixins.ListModelMixin):
  queryset=Article.objects.all()
  serilizer_class=ArticleSerializer
  def get(self,request):
      return self.list(request)
```

Comment: You've missed the 'a' in serializer_class

Comment: your question is your answer, please edit your question with some description about whats the issue.

Comment: Hello neha, please consider to state clearly what you are trying to do and what exactly your question is.

Answer (score 4):

it is  **serializer_class** not **serilizer_class**

Comment: Nor is it `serialized_class` thank you! Long day!

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward is to override the `serializer_class` attribute of `GenericAPIView`:

```
class GenericAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.ListModelMixin):

    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def get (self,request):
        return self.list(request)
```

Alternatively you can override the `get_serializer_class()` method of `GenericAPIView`:

```
class GenericAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.ListModelMixin):

    queryset = Article.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return ArticleSerializer

    def get (self,request):
        return self.list(request)
```

Second solution will be better if you need to use different serializers depending on the situation that might occur.